# edge sequence by vertex name

Tags: r, label, vertex, igraph, edges

Well, I'm working with the `igraph` package, and I'd like to pick the edges by the name that I've assigned to their vertex, in a tiny example..

```
library(igraph)

g <- barabasi.game(8)

labels<-c("G1","G2","G3","T1","T2","T3","H1","H2")

V(g)$name<-labels
```

Now My edge list hast this form

```
> E(g)
Edge sequence:

    [0] G2 -> G1
    [1] G3 -> G2
    [2] T1 -> G2
    [3] T2 -> G3
    [4] T3 -> G1
    [5] H1 -> G1
    [6] H2 -> H1
```

What i want now is to find a way of, instead of using this

```
E(g)[1%--%2]
```

doing something more like E(g)[G2%--%G1] (calling the vertex by the name i've assigned), or an equivalent way of knowing some edges attributes by the name of the vertex involved.

Comment: I've retagged your question to include `r` and `igraph`. Not having a tag related to a programming language was probably why your question has been viewed only two times (including me) since you asked it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the 0.5 branch of igraph, but the development version (0.6) adds support for referring to vertices based on their `name` attribute instead of their numeric IDs. I'm not sure how to do that as I am not familiar with the R interface. Try to subscribe to the [igraph-help mailing list](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/support.html) and ask there as this is definitely something that has been solved recently in igraph 0.6.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the vertex names in quotes. This gives identical output to using the vertex number. This works in igraph 0.7.1.

For example:

```
> E(g)[1%--%8]
Edge sequence:
    e         
e [7] H2 -> G1

> E(g)['H2'%--%'G1']
Edge sequence:
    e         
e [7] H2 -> G1
```